# Cannot load JSON on Table w/ RestSharp

Tags: ios, json, xamarin, tableview, restsharp

I am trying to load all the captions from the pictures on my Instagram Feed onto a Table using RestSharp and Xamarin.iOS, however whenever I try to run my code I always get this error:

[image: The Actual Error]

Here is how I am attempting to load the code here is my request:

```
var instagramAccessToken = instagram.Properties["access_token"].ToString();

        var client = new RestClient ("https://api.instagram.com/v1/");

        var request = new RestRequest("users/self/feed", Method.GET);
        request.AddParameter("access_token", instagramAccessToken);
        client.ExecuteAsync<List<RootObject>> (request, response => {
            // do work on UI thread
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
            InvokeOnMainThread(delegate {
                // pass the data to the TableSource class
                ((TableSource<RootObject>)table.Source).Data = response.Data;

                // make the TableView reload the data
                table.ReloadData();
            });
        });
```

I have confirmed that there is a working Access Token and that a working JSON string is returning. Here is the JSON object class that I have created for the Instagram Pictures:

```
public class InstaPic
    {
        Caption cap = new Caption();
        Pagination pag;
        Meta met;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return cap.text;
        }
    }

public class Pagination
{
    public string next_url { get; set; }
    public string next_max_id { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public int code { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int? id { get; set; }
}

public class Comments
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public List<object> data { get; set; }
}

public class Datum2
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string profile_picture { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
}

public class Likes
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public List<Datum2> data { get; set; }
}

public class LowResolution
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Thumbnail
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class StandardResolution
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Images
{
    public LowResolution low_resolution { get; set; }
    public Thumbnail thumbnail { get; set; }
    public StandardResolution standard_resolution { get; set; }
}

public class From
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string profile_picture { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
}

public class Caption
{
    public string created_time { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public From from { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string website { get; set; }
    public string profile_picture { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public string bio { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class LowResolution2
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class StandardResolution2
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Videos
{
    public LowResolution2 low_resolution { get; set; }
    public StandardResolution2 standard_resolution { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public object attribution { get; set; }
    public List<object> tags { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public Comments comments { get; set; }
    public string filter { get; set; }
    public string created_time { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public Likes likes { get; set; }
    public Images images { get; set; }
    public List<object> users_in_photo { get; set; }
    public Caption caption { get; set; }
    public bool user_has_liked { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public Videos videos { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Pagination pagination { get; set; }
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

And Finally here is the Data Source for My Table View:
    public class TableSource : UITableViewSource 
    {
        public List Data { get; set; }
        protected string cellIdentifier = "TableCell";

```
    public TableSource ()
    {
        Data = new List<T> ();
    }

    public TableSource(List<T> data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called by the TableView to determine how many cells to create for that particular section.
    /// </summary>
    public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        return 5;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when a row is touched
    /// </summary>
    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (OnRowSelected != null) {
            OnRowSelected (this, new RowSelectedEventArgs (tableView, indexPath));
        }
    }

    public class RowSelectedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public UITableView tableView { get; set; }
        public NSIndexPath indexPath { get; set; }

        public RowSelectedEventArgs(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) : base()
        { 
            this.tableView = tableView;
            this.indexPath = indexPath;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<RowSelectedEventArgs> OnRowSelected;

    /// <summary>
    /// Called by the TableView to get the actual UITableViewCell to render for the particular row
    /// </summary>
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        // request a recycled cell to save memory
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);
        // if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        if (cell == null)
            cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier);

        cell.TextLabel.Text = Data[indexPath.Row].ToString();

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Sorry for the overly long question! And thanks before hand for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are telling it that there are 5 rows in the table, regardless of how much data you actually have.  Since you are loading the data async, the first time the table loads there is no data.  Change this:

```
public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
{
    // return 5;
    if (Data == null) {
      return 0;
    else {
      return Data.Count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well now its says that 'Data' is not an instance of an object.

Comment: I have edited the Instagram Class to include a method I was using

Comment: Then you need to use the debugger to figure out why your data is not getting initialized.  Also, your use of Generics seems a little pointless - are you actually going to use these classes with multiple types?  I don't think that is causing the problem, but it muddies up what you're doing.

Comment: What is in the response string (response.Content)? Maybe the List<T> should be List<Datum> instead of List<RootObject> and you should pass in response.Data.data?